# File not found in springboot test class at multi-module Springboot project

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've a multi-module springboot project, the structure is shown below:

[image: prj structure]

There's a config file below the project root path, the ServiceTest class is a bean and will read the file when project started.

```
@Service
public class ServiceTest {

    String PATH = "conf/config";

    @PostConstruct
    public void readConf() throws IOException {

        File file = new File(PATH);

        String fileStr =  FileUtils.readFileToString(file,"utf-8");

        System.out.println("init success, config: "+fileStr);

    }
}
```

When project started, it performs fine with no error.

```
2022-05-27 17:06:16.779  INFO 18644 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-05-27 17:06:16.779  INFO 18644 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.62]
2022-05-27 17:06:16.842  INFO 18644 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-27 17:06:16.842  INFO 18644 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 584 ms
init success, config: abc
2022-05-27 17:06:17.038  INFO 18644 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-05-27 17:06:17.043  INFO 18644 --- [           main] com.test.App                             : Started App in 1.013 seconds (JVM running for 1.456)
2022-05-27 17:06:17.074  INFO 18644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-27 17:06:17.074  INFO 18644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-27 17:06:17.075  INFO 18644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

but when i started project with springboot test class, a FileNotFoundException occured.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'conf\config' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1805)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1822)
    at com.test.service.ServiceTest.readConf(ServiceTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

When I change the path in service class from `conf/config` to `../conf/config`, the test class is fine. I want to know how can I run the test class without change the file path. Is there any configure param in application.properties like classpath related?

Comment: The base path is the module where the test is running, and not the parent module. In your case mod1.  If you don't want to hardcode the path, then define it in application.properties in the resource folder of your test folder. And create a similar property for the source code.

Comment: that sounds good, which property are you referring to？is server.servlet.context-path ？but as far as i know, it is for http access.

Answer (score 0):

this problem solved by change the run configuration of unit test. The intellij idea default test template which set the `Working deretory` as `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` lead to this problem, change to empty works fine.